# What kind of chart is this?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, charts

This might not be the proper place to ask this, but I was not sure.

Have a look at the chart seen [here](http://s5.postimg.org/xt1jxr6k7/Image.jpg).

I need to create this chart in WPF but don't know its name. What is the proper term for this type of chart?

Comment: I don't think it has a name other than the generic "infographic".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow report in Google seems to be based off the [Sankey Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) which is also included in Google Visualization - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey

Answer (score 0):

Flow Report.

Google uses one, and here is a reference to it's name: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=en

> Like all flow reports, the Behavior Flow report displays nodes,
>   connections and exits, which represent the flow of your traffic.